# CountDownTimer paused and cancel

Tags: android, eclipse, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer in the constructor of my view class. it seems to work out. but I cant do `.cancel()`. Do anyone please help me out on my codings? heres my code.

```
private CountDownTimer countTimer;
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
            new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                countDowntimer = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                invalidate();
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                timer.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                if (Game.lifeCount <= 1) {
                    countDowntimer = String.valueOf("TIME'S UP!");
                    if (countmaze == 0) {
                        timesUpDialog1();
                    } else if (countmaze == 1) {
                        timesUpDialog2();
                    } else if (countmaze == 2) {
                        timesUpDialog3();
                    } else if (countmaze == 3)
                        timesUpDialog4();
                } else {
                    showGameoverDialog();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

the codes tells that the player will lose life whenever the time runs out then under my `onTouch event`

```
if (maze.isWrongAnswer()) {
    countTimer.cancel();
    //..some codes here
```

But whenever I come to this condition the **countTimer.cancel()** wont work. why? please help me out. thanks. by the way. I also want to have an `pause method` in my countdown. is there a simple way to do that? thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forget to put that countdown timer into your global variable :

```
private CountDownTimer countTimer;
public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
            countTimer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) { //<- in here bro
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                countDowntimer = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                invalidate();
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                timer.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                if (Game.lifeCount <= 1) {
                    countDowntimer = String.valueOf("TIME'S UP!");
                    if (countmaze == 0) {
                        timesUpDialog1();
                    } else if (countmaze == 1) {
                        timesUpDialog2();
                    } else if (countmaze == 2) {
                        timesUpDialog3();
                    } else if (countmaze == 3)
                        timesUpDialog4();
                } else {
                    showGameoverDialog();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

And for the pause, i'm using sharedPreferences to save the tick counter. then load it when i want to resume my countdown.

Comment: wow thanks sir. Sir had you try to use abstract class on CountDownTimer?